# Spark convert list to dataframe error: Schema for type Any is not supported

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I ma trying to make create dataframe by doing the following:

```
val df = Seq(
    ("tom", 25),
    ("andy", null)
).toDF("user", "rating")
```

but I get an error of "Schema for type Any is not supported".
I think the rating column is causing the problem.

I want the rating column to be

```
integer (nullable=true)
```

but i am not sure how to achieve that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Option`:

```
Seq(
  ("tom", Some(25)),
  ("andy", None)
).toDF("user", "rating")
```

You could also be more specific about the types and use `java.lang.Integer`:

```
Seq[(String, java.lang.Integer)](
  ("tom", 25),
  ("andy", null)
).toDF("user", "rating")
```

but the first method should be preferred.